Trouble with MatPaginator trying to create a generic component
I'm using angular-material to create a generic table. When I navigate to the details of an object in the table and when I want to open the table page from the menu, it does not render the data until I get some action with the paginator. I think that it is for the paginator, but, I don't have a solution.
Here is the class in typescript
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'pc-tabla-paginada',
  templateUrl: './tabla-paginada.component.html',
  styles: `
    #tableDiv { overflow-x: scroll; }
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TablaPaginadaComponent {

  @Input()
  public listaObjetos: any[] = [];

  @Input()
  public columnasAMostrar: string[] = [];

  @Input()
  public nombreColumnas : any = {};

  @Input()
  public encabezadoTabla: string = '';

  @Input()
  public pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 20];

  @Input()
  public pageSize: number = 5;

  @Input()
  public length: number = 0;

  @Output()
  public page: EventEmitter<PageEvent> = new EventEmitter();

  @Output()
  public objeto: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public emitPaginationData(event: PageEvent) {

    this.page.emit(event);
  }

  public enviarObjeto(elemento: any) {
    this.objeto.emit(elemento);
  }

  public esFecha( value: any ): boolean {
    if ( value === '' || value === null || value === undefined) return false;

    const datoProbar = new Date(value);

    if ( typeof value === 'object' && datoProbar.toString() !== 'Invalid Date') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

}

Here is the HTML
<div class="row col-12">
  <div class="row col-12">
    <h2>{{ encabezadoTabla }}</h2>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <div class="mat-elevation-z8 row" id="tableDiv">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="listaObjetos">

        @for (columna of columnasAMostrar; track $index) {
          <ng-container [matColumnDef] = columna >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ nombreColumnas[columna] }} </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let elemento">
              @if ( columna === 'enableEdition') {
                <button mat-raised-button
                  (click)="enviarObjeto(elemento)">
                  <mat-icon>more_horiz</mat-icon>
                  Más
                </button>
              } @else {
                @if ( esFecha(elemento[columna]) ) {
                  {{elemento[columna] | date:'medium': '':'es-ES' }}
                } @else {
                  {{elemento[columna]}}
                }
              }
            </td>
          </ng-container>
        }

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnasAMostrar"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnasAMostrar;"></tr>

      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <mat-paginator
        [pageSizeOptions] = "pageSizeOptions"
        [length] = "length"
        [pageSize] = "pageSize"
        showFirstLastButtons
        aria-label="Lista de Pedidos"
        (page)="emitPaginationData($event)">
      </mat-paginator>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

As it is a generic component, I will call it like this
<pc-tabla-paginada
          [listaObjetos]="listaObjetos"
          [columnasAMostrar]="columnasAMostrar"
          [nombreColumnas]="nombreColumnas"
          [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
          [pageSize]="pageSize"
          [length]="length"
          [encabezadoTabla]="encabezadoTabla"
          (page)="getPaginationData($event)"
          ></pc-tabla-paginada>

So, in the constructor of the object, I'm not subscribing to any petition because it's generic. I have looked for a lot of solutions, but none of them fit my problem.

You could observe the length of your data and manually trigger the (page) event for the first rendering when initializing the paginator. Please trigger it with a non-zero data length and refer to the handleEvent method in the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples

Then, create a PageEvent, let's say initialEvent. use @ViewChild, this.paginator.page.emit(initialEvent) to trigger the rendering.

I tried your suggestion, but dont work. The main problem is that the Paginator is not initialized at the moment of the creation of the page. It gets the data, but it is not initialized.

I'll post an answer for you for your reference.

The issue you're experiencing, where the data doesn't render until you interact with the paginator, is likely related to change detection in Angular. Let's go through some potential solutions:

Force Change Detection:
Since you're using OnPush change detection strategy, you might need to force change detection when the data is updated. You can do this by injecting ChangeDetectorRef into your component and calling detectChanges() when the data is updated.

import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class TablaPaginadaComponent {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  @Input() set listaObjetos(value: any[]) {
    this._listaObjetos = value;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
  get listaObjetos(): any[] {
    return this._listaObjetos;
  }
  private _listaObjetos: any[] = [];
}


Use ngOnChanges:
Implement the OnChanges interface to detect when the input properties change:

import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

export class TablaPaginadaComponent implements OnChanges {
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['listaObjetos']) {
      // Perform any necessary updates
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  }
}


Use async pipe:
If your data is coming from an Observable, consider using the async pipe in your template:

<table mat-table [dataSource]="listaObjetos | async">
  <!-- ... -->
</table>


Trigger change detection in the parent component:
Ensure that change detection is triggered in the parent component when the data is updated:

import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  updateData() {
    // Update your data
    this.listaObjetos = [...]; // Create a new reference
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}


Use trackBy function:
Implement a trackBy function to help Angular identify which items have changed:

export class TablaPaginadaComponent {
  trackByFn(index: number, item: any): any {
    return item.id; // Use a unique identifier from your data
  }
}

And in your template:
<table mat-table [dataSource]="listaObjetos" [trackBy]="trackByFn">
  <!-- ... -->
</table>


Ensure data is loaded before rendering:
In the parent component, you might want to ensure that the data is fully loaded before passing it to the child component:

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  listaObjetos: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    // Your data loading logic here
    this.someService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.listaObjetos = data;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
}


Defer rendering:
You can use *ngIf to defer rendering until the data is available:

<pc-tabla-paginada
  *ngIf="listaObjetos.length > 0"
  [listaObjetos]="listaObjetos"
  ...
></pc-tabla-paginada>

Try implementing these solutions one at a time, starting with forcing change detection (#1) as it's likely to be the most straightforward fix.

The #6 worked for me. I put the cdr.detectChanges() in the parent constructor and work. Thanks!

As mentioned in the comment, I also have tried several ways to solve the issue. Here is my implementation for reference:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-paginator',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    StylePaginatorDirective,
    MatIconModule,
  ],
  template: `
    <mat-paginator
      #paginator
      appStylePaginator
      [showTotalPages]="2"
      (page)="handlePageEvent($event)"
      [length]="length"
      [pageSize]="pageSize"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      [showFirstLastButtons]="showFirstLastButtons"
      [pageSizeOptions]="showPageSizeOptions ? pageSizeOptions : []"
      [hidePageSize]="hidePageSize"
      [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
      aria-label="Select page"
    >
    </mat-paginator>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .mat-mdc-paginator-range-label {
        display: none;
      }

      .mat-mdc-mini-fab {
        --mdc-fab-small-container-shape: 5px;
        margin-right: 1rem;
      }

      .mat-mdc-icon-button[disabled] .mat-mdc-paginator-icon {
        fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
      }
    `,
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class PaginatorComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() length!: number | null;
  @Input() pageSize!: number;
  @Input() pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];

  pageIndex = 0;
  hidePageSize = true;
  showPageSizeOptions = false;
  showFirstLastButtons = false;
  disabled = false;
  pageEvent!: PageEvent;

  @ViewChild('paginator', { static: true }) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  handlePageEvent(e: PageEvent) {
    this.pageEvent = e;
    this.length = e.length;
    this.pageSize = e.pageSize;
    this.pageIndex = e.pageIndex;
  }

  private triggerInitialPageEvent() {
    // Create an initial PageEvent
    if (this.length === 0 || !this.length) return;
    const initialPageEvent: PageEvent = {
      pageIndex: this.pageIndex,
      pageSize: this.pageSize,
      length: this.length,
    };

    // Trigger the handlePageEvent method
    this.paginator.page.emit(initialPageEvent);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['length'] || changes['pageSize']) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.triggerInitialPageEvent();
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      });
    }
  }
}


I tried this solution and it does not work for me. The main problem is that the paginator is undefined when it is constructed the component, so, I can't emit any event. Thanks!

I noticed you're using onPush detection. If not using the zoneless environment, use the default detection by removing the onPush line.
